# How to "expand" a dict with iterables into a list of dict in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

for example i have a

```
{
    "key1":[1,2,3],
    "key2":[1,2]
}
```

And I want to change it into

```
[{"key1":1, "key2":1},{"key1":1, "key2":2},{"key1":2, "key2":1}...]
```

i achieve this by using eval, and i think recursion also help. But is there any better solution?

Comment: So you achieve this with eval, what was your solution?

Comment: recursion always helps :P

Comment: @metatoaster basically using `({"a":b, "c":d}... for b in d["a"] for  d in d['c'])`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry but only one key is produced

Answer (score 3):

```
d = {
    "key1":[1,2,3],
    "key2":[1,2]
}
from itertools import product
[{'key1':i,'key2':j}  for i,j in product(d['key1'],d['key2'])]


[{'key1': 1, 'key2': 1}, {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}, {'key1': 2, 'key2': 1}, {'key1': 2, 'key2': 2}, {'key1': 3, 'key2': 1}, {'key1': 3, 'key2': 2}]
```

Comment: Dicts are not ordered! You have no guarantee that `i` is `key1` and `j` is `key2`. Better use `product(d["key1], d["key2])`

Comment: @tobias_k changed it to use take the values from keys manually